# How Set Different Proxies For Each WebBrowser Control In A Form - All Possible Ways

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, proxy, webbrowser-control

i am looking for a custom `WebBrowser` control that supports different proxy for individual `WebBrowser` in a form.
regular `WebBrowser` control is working with IE and for one `WebBrowser` control i can set proxy, but what about the other Ones?
is there a way to change regular `WebBrowser` control for doing that or is there a way for my purpose?

thanks in advance

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not possible because all `WebBrowser` instances share the same UrlMon/WinInet session per-process. Although it'd be great if @EricLaw commented on this.

Comment: yes, we want EricLaw here... this is very very interesting and you know what am i saying.

Comment: This is generally not possible for all the reasons described here. Proxy settings are per-process, not per-WebOC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a crazy idea for you. Apparently, `UrlMkSetSessionOption` and `InternetSetOption` can only configure the proxy setting per-process. However, if your `WebBrowser` instances access different websites, and there is one-to-one or many-to-one mapping between URLs and the corresponding proxy settings, you can use *IE proxy automatic configuration (PAC) script* to return a proxy based upon specific URL:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361918.aspx

The PAC script location can be `file://`-based and (I believe) you can generate it on-the-fly and then set as active with `InternetSetOption`.

Comment: This sorta works, in general (although caching of the proxy address is per-host, IIRC), but note that you can't use File:// based PAC URLs in IE11 or later.